# element reaches to final state without showing transition/animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a `div` element inside `td` element(`div` is the child of `td` element) using javascript.

```
newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.className = "class";        
tdEle.appendChild(newDiv);
```

I am also assigning a class to this newly created div. This positions the `div` element at the top-left corner inside the `td` element

```
.class{
    position: absolute;
    height: 2%;
    width: 2%;
    background-color: azure;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition-duration: 350ms;
}
```

I am trying to make a transition so that the `newDiv` element covers the whole `td` element using JS. For this, I am doing something like this.

I have this in my CSS.

```
.class.scale {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

To trigger this animation automatically, I am using this in JS

```
newDiv.classList.add('scale');
```

When I run the code, the `newDiv` does cover the whole `td` but transition animation is not being displayed. What am I doing wrong? any other way I can achieve this effect using JS.

EDIT:
The solution provided works perfectly but I hid some details in my original problem. Because of which I am not getting the designed outcome.

DETAILS:
I don't have 1 `<td>` element but `n` of them. and I want to dynamically create a `div` inside each one of those `<td>`s for the same transition explained above.

```
tds.forEach(tdEle => {
                    let id = getID(tdEle); // some logic to get the ID for <td> element
                    console.log(id);
                    let tdEle = document.getElementById(id); // get the actual td element
                    // append a div at top left corner
                    newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    newDiv.className = "class";
                    tdEle.appendChild(newDiv);
                    setTimeout(function() { // <---------------------------------
                        newDiv.classList.add('scale');
                    });
                });
```

rest is the same...

when I use the given solution. This transition only happens for the `div` that was appended to the last `td` element. The class `class` was added to this last `div` only and not to the other `div`s. I  guess this is because of the setTimeout() function???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to set the properties to animate, in your CSS:

```
transition-property: width, height;
```

Then, depending on whether you're adding the class immediatly or not, you might need to wait for the DOM to be updated before adding the class, otherwise you won't see the animation:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  newDiv.classList.add('scale');
});
```

### Demo

```js
newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.className = "class";        
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

setTimeout(function() { // <---------------------------------
  newDiv.classList.add('scale');
});
```

```css
.class{
    position: absolute;
    height: 2%;
    width: 2%;
    background-color: blue;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition-duration: 350ms;
    transition-property: width, height; /* <----------------- */
}
.class.scale {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: hey, this solution works perfectly given the details I provided. But I kind of did not provide all the details for the problem. And when I use this solution, it does not work for my original problem(obviously because exact details were not provided). I have provided more details. maybe u could help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: @rayan What is `n_div`?

Comment: @rayan You forgot to declare `newDiv` locally, so it's global. Add `const` or `let` in front of it: https://jsfiddle.net/3n9x8abt/

Comment: Thanks. just one last question. all the transitions are happening at the same time. Is it possible to run these transitions one after the other? that is one finishes first and then the next one starts. No need to do it, just give me some pointers on how to do that. Thanks again

Comment: Sure, you can simply add a delay to the setTimeout: https://jsfiddle.net/j19zrgs6/ (they will happen in the order of the `forEach`, don't know if that's what you want?)

Comment: I had to change the delay for setTimeout. But yes, this is pretty much what I wanted. Thanks